# Using CIFS with Azure Storage with Debian 3.2.0 Kernel

Tags: linux, azure, debian, mount, cifs

I'm using Debian Wheezy with the 3.2.0 kernel.  I'm using the latest cifs-utils from testing branch, I also tried the stable branch of cifs-utils and had the same issue.  What is occurring is that when I try to mount the CIFS share on windows azure storage it gives the following error:

```
CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation
```

I'm using the following command:

```
mount.cifs --verbose //abc.file.core.windows.net/abc /mnt/cifs -o vers=2.1,username=abc,password=abc,dir_mode=0775,file_mode=0775
```

I'm able to create a socket to the hostname on port 443 TCP and both ports 443 UDP and TCP are open on my firewall.

Comment: The CIFS implementation you are using must support SMB2. See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/holgerkenn/archive/2014/09/17/linux-and-azure-files-you-might-need-some-help-here.aspx

Comment: I have specified to use version 2.1 with mount.cifs as my original post suggest and I'm using version 6.4 of cifs-utils.